# 100 requests per minute for a duration of 20 minutes - Load/performance testing

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, web-api-testing

I am doing load test on my system using Jmeter. the requirement is I need to generate 150 requests per minute for a duration of 20 minutes constantly.
I tried with below approaches

1. I tried by giving this configuration.
   No of threads - 3000 [150 req/min * 20 mins]
   rampup period - 1200sec [20mins * 60]

   But here test stopped after creation of 2004 thread. by giving
   this error

   Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread “Thread Group 1-2004”
   Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached in thread Thread[#51,StandardJMeterEngine,6,main]. See log file for details
2. Used concurrency thread group with below details
   Target concurrency - 150
   ramp up time - 1 min
   hold target rate time - 20 mins

   but here no of samples collected are more than 3000 [150 req *20 sec] which i feel is not correct

Is it possible to create exact load according to my requirement in Jmeter(150 req/min ->duration of 20 mins) or should I explore other tools like locust??

3. tried with precision timers (attaching screen shots)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBKwv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVNOZ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q881M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of [relationship between users and hits per second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second) is not correct.

When JMeter thread (virtual user) is started it begins executing Samplers **as fast as it can**. The throughput (number of requests per second) mainly depends on the response time.

For example:

- you have 1 user and 1 second response time - the load will be 1 request per second
- you have 1 user and 2 seconds response time - the load will be 0.5 requests per second
- you have 2 users and 2 seconds response time - the load will be 1 requests per second
- you have 4 users and 2 seconds response time - the load will be 2 requests per second
- etc.

If you want to slow down JMeter to the desired number of requests per minute it can be done using [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers).

For example:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer):

  [image]
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer):

  [image]
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

  [image]

Comment: HI @Dmitri , I have attached screenshots of the config I have tried,  total samples is showing as 150 . Have I done anything wrong ??

Comment: You need to increase the number of loops in the Thread Group. Also 150 users might be too much for your application as there are response times almost 2 minutes and 10% of errors, try decreasing the users to i.e. 10-15 and adjust up if the throughput will be lower than your expectations [3 Common Issues When Running JMeter Scripts and How to Solve Them](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scripts)